# how can i use <pre> html tag in tcpdf library?

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

```
<?php
require 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
include 'clasess/DBConnect.php'; 
$db= DataBase::getInstance();
$query = mysql_qstrong textuery("SELECT * from post  order by post_id DESC"); 
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 018', PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->SetTextColor(100,7,20);
$pdf->SetFont('aealarabiya', '', 18);
$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);
$pdf->setRTL(false);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $data = "<pre>". $rows['content'] ."</pre>";

    $pdf->writeHTML($data ,true,0,true,0);
    $pdf->Ln();
}

$pdf->Output();
```

when i use pre tag  .. my Arabic words show like this ????
How can I solve Arabic language problem when using pre tage
 the problem shows in the image

[image]

Comment: The pre tag is most probably rendered using different font that does not have support for your language. You should manually select some monotype  font with support for your language and try to print it directly.

Comment: how can i do that?